# 15.8 GB of 18 GB ram is "system reserved" leaving me with only 2.2 GB. Cross-Computer issue

Tags: windows-10, laptop, memory

So I have 16gb of ram in my computer, but 15.8 gb is system reserved according to task manager. Windows (10) detects 16gb, just all system reserved aside 2.2gb. By "cross-computer" I mean it happens in separate laptops. Is it a problem with the RAM? They are 2 8gb sticks, one philips, other kingston, both ddr3. As single sticks, they reserve 6.4gb, leaving me 2.6gb to use. Is it a problem with the RAM itself? I can test with 2gb sticks if needed, but don't really wanna take case off again. One laptop is Acer, other is Toshiba.

Answer (score 0):

**THIS IS A WORKING ANSWER**

I spent quite a bit of time upgrading to 64-bit, and downloading all my programs again, but upgrading to windows 10 fixed the RAM problem entirely, turning 15.8 GB system reserved to 100 MB reserved, which is actually less than it usually reserves!

Comment: The maximum amount of memory for a 32-bit operating system is only 4 GB.  If you really do have 16 GB of memory installed, that would indeed be the explanation for the System Reserve behavior you describe, only approximately 3.2 GB would have been usable by a 32-bit installation of Windows.